# issue while writing into postgresql database in glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

Hey I am trying to write data into postgresql db from glue job but getting below error
`IllegalArgumentException: Option 'dbtable' can not be empty.`

Below is my code which seems to be correct

How I read from s3

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            format_options={"multiline": False},
            connection_type="s3",
            format="json",
            connection_options={
                "paths": [s3path],
                "recurse": True,
            },
            transformation_ctx=S3_TO_CUSTOM_TRANSFORM,
        )
```

And then after some transformation I try to writeusing below code

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame=df,
            connection_type="postgresql",
            connection_options={
                "url": "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:port/db",
                "user": "username",
                "password": "password",
                "dbtable": "table_name"
            }
        )
```

Comment: AWS doc mentions this
"dbtable": The database table to read from. For JDBC data stores that support schemas within a database, specify schema.table-name. If a schema is not provided, then the default "public" schema is used.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag thanks for answering then what option should we use for writing into database

Comment: db table is optional field IMO, remove that field and try connecting

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag still got same issue

Comment: can u show me the select query which you use to read the data fropm db

Comment: ```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame=df,
            connection_type="postgresql",
            connection_options={
                "url": "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:port/db",
                "user": "username",
                "password": "password",
                "dbtable": "your_schema.your_table"
            }
        )
```

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag `dbtable.your_schema.your_table` here `your_schema` refers to db name right? If yes then i got the same error. And bydefault it uses public schema and my db have public schema

Comment: if you have created a schema in db then add the schema name. You can try schema as "public" too.

Comment: Even trying with `public.mytable_name`  i got the same error